# Fullscreen to Maximize on MacOS using JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, electron

I'm creating some custom MacOS 'Traffic Lights' for my React/Electron App. I've managed to get the Close and Minimize buttons to work perfectly fine, however, my Maximize (green) button will go fullscreen but when its clicked again it will not return to normal.

Here is my code for the functions that are called to the buttons: https://sourceb.in/8f930dc034.js

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `currentWindow.isFullScreen()` instead of `currentWindow.isMaximized()`.

You're using `currentWindow.isMaximized()` to check if you're full screened when you should use `currentWindow.isFullScreen()` instead.

See the docs for: [`currentWindow.isFullScreen()`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winisfullscreen)

---

Old answer:

I had problems creating my own traffic lights too, but it turns out Electron can do this for you with the `titleBarStyle` option.

To use it:

```
var winObj = new BrowserWindow({
    titleBarStyle:   'hidden',
});
```

This will create some native traffic lights in the top right window corner.

Here are different values for the `titleBarStyle` option:

`default`

- Results in the standard gray opaque Mac title bar.

`hidden` (Used in the example).

- Results in a hidden title bar and a full size content window, yet the title bar still has the standard window controls ("traffic lights") in the top left.

`hiddenInset`

- Results in a hidden title bar with an alternative look where the traffic light buttons are slightly more inset from the window edge.

Have a play around with it and see what works for you.

See the docs for the [`BrowserWindow` options](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) (search for `titleBarStyle`).

Comment: My ```titleBarStyle``` is set to ``` hidden```. The reason I want to create custom buttons is to allow them to be visible in the same place when in fullscreen mode

Comment: Ah, my bad @Vidsify, I've updated my answer. I hope it helps :)

Comment: You legend. Thank you for your help